# Creating files in loop, adding files instead of overwriting

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous

EDIT: LOOP OVERWROTE THE ARRAYS

I'm using nodejs.  I want to overwrite my existing files. When running the function once it does overwrite the files. When putting it in a loop it doesnt overwrite the files but adds new contents.

See below for a code snippet. How can i fix this?

```
function writefiles() {
    fs.writeFile("hello1.json", hello1, 'utf8', function (err) {
            console.log("File Created");
            if (err) {
                console.log("An error occured while writing JSON Object to File.");
                return console.log(err);
            }
        });

    fs.writeFile("hello1.json", hello2, 'utf8', function (err) {
            console.log("File Created");
            if (err) {
                console.log("An error occured while writing JSON Object to File.");
                return console.log(err);
            }
        });
    }
    setInterval(Writefiles, 3000);
```

Comment: @TomO.Hi, thank for the suggestion unfortunatly it doesnt. I think it has something to do with async

Comment: I think your issue here is that you use `fs.writeFile` which is asynchronous. A quick way to fix this would be to use `fs.writeFileSync`.

Comment: @GMartigny Thank you for the answer I have created this fs.writeFileSync("hello1.json", hello2, 'utf8',  {'flags': 'w'} function (err) and fs.writeFileSync("hello1.json", hello2, 'utf8'  function (err). But it is still overwriting the file

Comment: I think that you must use fs.appendFileSync, hello1 and hello2 must be strings, and setInterval(Writefiles, 3000); must be setInterval(writefiles, 3000);

Comment: Take a look at [the documentation for `fs.writeFileSync`](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v12.x/docs/api/fs.html#fs_fs_writefile_file_data_options_callback). You want to override your files or not ?

Comment: @GMartigny I want to override the files

Comment: This code starts two `fs.writeFile()` operations targetting the same file at the same time.  That's a disaster with unpredictable results.  So, the current design is just wrong.  Since it makes no sense to write a file and then immediate write it again with different contents, I have no idea what you actually want to do.  Please explain in the question exactly what the desired outcome is and explain an outcome that makes sense.  Also, if you're using a loop, please show the code for the loop because that is probably relevant too.  `setInterval()` is not a loop.

Answer (score 0):

```
function writefiles() {
fs.appendFileSync("hello1.json", 'hello1', 'utf8', function (err) {
    console.log("File Created");
    if (err) {
        console.log("An error occured while writing JSON Object to File.");
        return console.log(err);
    }
});

fs.appendFileSync("hello1.json", 'hello2', 'utf8', function (err) {
    console.log("File Created");
    if (err) {
        console.log("An error occured while writing JSON Object to File.");
        return console.log(err);
    }
});}


setInterval(writefiles, 3000);
```

Comment: Thanks for the feedback I do not want to append to the file I want to overide

Comment: Try this fs.writeFileSync(path,content,{encoding:'utf8',flag:'w'})